# nodejs/express, Controller send the response before to get the result of function setInterval

Tags: node.js, express, async-await, promise, setinterval

the problem is :
In Controller, the response is send before the result of condition into function setInterval

Steps :

1. Controller run function setInterval
2. Then send the response to frontend with res.status.json
3. The function setInterval run
4. condition of setInterval work and finish
5. setInterval don't return the resultto controller
6. the controller have already sent a res...

```
import checkHealth from "./checkHealth.js";

async function checkHealthInterval(labelData) {
  console.log("labelData==>", labelData);

  let resultInterval = { health: "", message: "" };
  let i = 1;
  let interval;

  interval = await setInterval(async () => {
    let healthCheckers = await checkHealth();

    let healthCheckerStatus;
    if (labelData== "example1") {
      healthCheckerStatus = healthCheckers.statusInstanceGlobal;
      console.log(
        "healthCheckerStatus value from tenant1 : ",
        healthCheckerStatus
      );
    } else {
      healthCheckerStatus = healthCheckers.statusWam1Wam2;
      console.log(
        "healthCheckerStatus value from tenant2 : ",
        healthCheckerStatus
      );
    }
    i++;
    if (healthCheckerStatus !== true && i > 36) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      console.log("VMs are UNHEALTHY in the end of interval or before the end");
      this.isProcessing = false;
      throw new ApiError(
        500,
        "VMs are UNHEALTHY in the end of interval or before the end"
      );
    } else if (healthCheckerStatus == true) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      console.log(
        `VMs ${labelData} are HEALTHY and successfully started!`
      );
      resultInterval.health = "healthy";
      resultInterval.message = "VMs are successfully started!";
      console.log("resultInterval into interval===>", resultInterval);

      return resultInterval
    }
  }, 10000);
  console.log("Script interval is running to check health");

  return interval
}
export { checkHealthInterval };
```

```
getStartVms = async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("You asked to start VMs: starting VMs");
    try {
      this.isProcessing = true;
      const responseStart = await this.instanceService.startInstances();

      // use interval to checkHealth of Vms with import function checkHealth()
      const resultInterval = await checkHealthInterval(responseStart?.labelData); 
    

      res.status(200).json({
         health: "healthy",
         message: "VMs are successfully started!",
      });
       this.isProcessing = false;
       io.emit("processChanged", this.isProcessing);
      
      
    } catch (err) {
      this.isProcessing = false;
      io.emit("processChanged", this.isProcessing);
      next(err);
    }
  };
```

Comment: inside your func, change it from just async to return a promise i.e return new Promise(....) and resolve where your doing `return resultInterval`

Comment: Thanks, it perfectly working! (on the other side, I always try not to use promises. I wonder if there is a simple solution with refactoring and only await/async?)

Comment: issue is setInterval its a ticker with a callback, so there's nothing to await onto, see how this package does it https://www.npmjs.com/package/interval-promise or just use a promise is nothing wrong with using it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.